# How do I replicate installed package selections from one Debian system to another? (Debian Wheezy)

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to set up a staging environment in a VM, in order to test updates before applying them to my main system.

In order to do so, I have done a basic installation of Debian Wheezy (same as on the main system) in the VM, then ran as root from within the VM:

```
# dpkg --clear-selections
# dpkg --add-architecture i386
# apt-get update
# ssh me@main-system 'dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall' | \
  dpkg --set-selections
```

The i386 architecture is unfortunately needed in my case; the system is amd64 native.

The problem is with `dpkg --set-selections` run in the VM. I do have some packages that require special handling (those are actually the main reason why I want a staging environment in the first place) but when I run the last command above, I get about a gazillion lines of output like:

```
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line NNN: package-name
```

for packages that really should be available in the base system. Examples include `xterm`, `yelp` and `zip`.

Now for my question:

**What is the specific process for transferring the package selection list from one Debian system to another** (assuming same Debian release level, in Wheezy) **and then subsequently applying those changes?** The goal is that both have the same list of installed packages, ideally such that doing a `diff` between the outputs of `dpkg --get-selections` or `dpkg --list` on the two comes back showing no differences.

The `grep -v deinstall` part is borrowed from [Prevent packages from being removed after doing `dpkg --set-selections`](https://askubuntu.com/a/345231/11751) over on Ask Ubuntu.

I have changed the source in the VM to be the same as on the main system, also installing `apt-transport-https`:

```
deb https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/debian/ wheezy main non-free
deb-src https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/debian/ wheezy main non-free
deb https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/debian/ wheezy-updates main non-free
deb-src https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/debian/ wheezy-updates main non-free
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.zfsonlinux.org/debian wheezy main
```

Looking at the --set-selections output, I'm seeing:

```
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: a2ps
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: abiword
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: abiword-common
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: abiword-plugin-grammar
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: abiword-plugin-mathview
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: accountsservice
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1: acl
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 4: aglfn
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 4: aisleriot
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 4: alacarte
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 4: alien
...
```

The line numbers looked odd, and the corresponding portion of the output of --get-selections is:

```
a2ps install
abiword install
abiword-common install
abiword-plugin-grammar install
abiword-plugin-mathview install
accountsservice install
acl install
acpi-support-base install
acpid install
adduser install
aglfn install
aisleriot install
alacarte install
alien install
```

Notice that in between `acl` and `aglfn` are `acpi-support-base`, `acpid` and `adduser` *for which no errors are being reported*. It seems that the packages for which errors are being reported are either `un` according to `dpkg -l`, or `dpkg -l` doesn't have any idea at all about them (`dpkg-query: no packages found matching ...`). I know there are some locally installed packages, but not many. `i386` doesn't figure until `gcc-4.7-base:i386 install` *much* farther down the list (line 342 in the --get-selections output).

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections … | … dpkg --set-selections` is the way to replicate package selections. If it's failing for you, you're going to need to provide more information as to why. Post your full set of sources on both systems, the output from `dpkg --get-selections`, and the full transcript from `dpkg --get-selections` (maybe we can discern a pattern by seeing what works and what doesn't). If the main system amd64 or i386? Does it work if you don't add the i386 architecture?

Comment: @Gilles Does it really need to be the *full* output from `dpkg --get-selections` (and I assume you meant the `dpkg --set-selections` transcript?)? Even just the former is over 3,600 lines and right around 100 KB.

Comment: You need to post enough for us to discern the pattern of which packages trigger errors and which ones don't (unless you can figure out by yourself). A copy of `/var/lib/dpkg/Packages` (which is even longer) could be useful, too — this could be a symptom of a broken Packages file.

Comment: @Gilles Interesting point. I hadn't really considered the possibility, but I do use different mirrors on these. Let me see if it still happens if I point the VM at the same Debian mirror. Stand by.

Comment: @Gilles That didn't really make any discernable difference, but I did find something else. See the updated question.

Comment: You can add a link to a gist paste, for example. Note the Ruby script `gist-paste` is a painless way of pasting files.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To clone a Debian installation, use the [`apt-clone`](http://chris.olstrom.com/software/apt-clone/) utility. It's available (as a separate package, not part of the default installation) in Debian since wheezy and in Ubuntu since 12.04. On the existing machine, run

```
apt-clone clone foo
```

This creates a file `foo.apt-clone.tar.gz`. Copy it to the destination machine, and run

```
apt-get install apt-clone
apt-clone restore foo.apt-clone.tar.gz
```

If you're working with an old system where `apt-clone` isn't available, or if you just want to replicate the list of installed packages but not any configuration file, here are the manual steps.

- On the source machine:

  ```
  cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d >sources.list
  dpkg --get-selections >selections.list
  apt-mark showauto >auto.list
  ```
- On the target machine:

  ```
  cp sources.list /etc/apt/
  apt-get update
  /usr/lib/dpkg/methods/apt/update /var/lib/dpkg/
  dpkg --set-selections <selections.list
  apt-get dselect-upgrade
  xargs apt-mark auto <auto.list
  ```

---

I believe that you're affected by an incompatible change in dpkg that first made it into wheezy. See [bug #703092](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=703092) for background.

The short story is that `dpkg --set-selections` now only accepts package names that are present in the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status` or `/var/lib/dpkg/available`. If you only use APT to manage packages, like most people, then `/var/lib/dpkg/available` is not kept up-to-date.

After running `apt-get update` and before running `dpkg --set-selections` and `apt-get -u dselect-upgrade`, run the following command:

```
apt-cache dumpavail >/tmp/apt.avail
dpkg --merge-avail /tmp/apt.avail
```

From jessie onwards, you can simplify this to

```
apt-cache dumpavail | dpkg --merge-avail
```

Alternatively, run

```
/usr/lib/dpkg/methods/apt/update /var/lib/dpkg/
```

or even simpler

```
apt-get install dctrl-tools
sync-available
```

Another simple method that doesn't require installing an additional package but will download the package lists again is

```
dselect update
```

See the [dpkg FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_Why_does_.27.27dpkg_--set-selections.27.27_not_record_selections_for_unknown_packages.3F) for more information. (This is mentioned in the dpkg man page, but more in a way that would remind you of the issue if you were already aware, not in a way that explains how to solve the problem!)

Note that cloning a package installation with `dpkg --set-selections` doesn't restore the automatic/manual mark in APT. See [Restoring all data and dependencies from dpkg --set-selections '*'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101931/restoring-all-data-and-dependencies-from-dpkg-set-selections) for more details. You can save the marks on the source system with

```
apt-mark showauto >auto.list
```

and restore them on the target system with

```
xargs apt-mark auto <auto.list
```

Comment: This problem ought to be much more visible than it is. I can't believe I've not heard of it before!

Comment: Interesting. Going to give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yeah, I'm surprised that I never heard of it before today. I can't believe I haven't used `dpkg --set-selections` since pre-wheezy!

Comment: Okay, that gave a very much shorter list of warnings from `--set-selections`. Now how do I apply the changes? Even `apt-get -u dist-upgrade` only mentions a handful of packages (all ZFS-related) where there should be hundreds if not thousands of packages affected.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's `apt-get -u dselect-upgrade`

Comment: *Great!* Turns out I didn't give the VM enough disk space to fit everything in there. The package list however looks easily big enough to make sense, after apt-get update + dump/merge-avail + set-selections + apt-mark. This certainly answers the question, but if you can add a TL;DR with just the commands in the correct order (as a bullet list or something) it'd be near perfect.

Comment: Below "On the source machine:" I think it should read `apt-mark showauto` rather than just `apt-mark auto`. The system doesn't allow me to suggest an edit as it is just adding 4 (<6) characters!

Comment: @Gilles will this approach copies all applications (even custom ones that are not found in the ubuntu sw centre) installed on my linux machine and then installs them in the new machine?

Comment: @Tak With `apt-clone`, yes. With the manual method as I describe it in my answer, yes, as long as you installed them through apt or an apt front-end, i.e. it's something that gets updated when you do a system update, but not if it's something you installed manually with dpkg, to do that you'd have to have the `.deb` file around.

Answer (score 1):

#### How I did it

0. On ***source*** host:

   ```
   apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
   dpkg --get-selections >/tmp/source.sel
   cat /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   care about `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` if used...

   Then copy *`source.sel`* file to destination host.
1. On ***destination*** host:

   ```
   vi /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

adapt *sources.list* even with different mirrors, but same *component* list.

```
    apt-get update
    dselect update
    dselect upgrade
    dpkg --set-selections </tmp/source.sel
    dselect install
```

And now, my **destination host** is currently installing a lot of things, then I could take some time for posting this.

Comment: Perhaps 'dselect upgrade' should be 'dselect update' in the 'How I did it' description above.