# Preparing a Ubuntu install for sharing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, images, development

I have a virtual version of Ubuntu running in VirtualBox. Currently I have lots of personal information in it. I want to share the virtual image disk with other developers, but I don't want them to be able to get all my personal info. What should I make sure to delete before distributing this vm to other developers? I deleted all old projects and cleared all browser history. What else should I do?

Comment: Sharing the whole VM is not a good idea. Instead, you should be able to build a fresh VM and copy just those things into it that you want to share. If you can't reproduce your development environment, you're in trouble anyway...

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious place for personal information is under `/home`, but there may be private information elsewhere, such as:

- In logs (IP addresses, email addresses, etc.)
- In email (`/var/mail`)
- In the printer spooler (`/var/spool/cups`)
- Under `/etc` (e.g. network configuration)
- In deleted files that can be carved out of the disk image
- (This is not an exhaustive list!)

Rather than scrubbing the existing installation, it would be best to reproduce a fresh installation, without inputting any private data. [Use `apt-clone` to reproduce the package installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208047/how-do-i-transfer-installed-packages-and-settings-from-one-distro-to-another/208163#208163). If you installed software manually, copy `/opt` or `/usr/local` or `/var/www` or `/srv` (if you installed software manually in other locations, you did it wrong, so do it right this time). If you made any modification under `/etc` you'll need to reproduce those; hopefully you used [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) to keep track of them (if you didn't keep track of them, you have a problem: how do you remember what you changed, to look for issues?).