# Generate apt-offline bundle for use across many machines

Tags: apt, apt-offline

I'm trying to use apt-offline to install packages on many machines (using ansible), so I need to avoid generating a machine-specific signature file (e.g. `sudo apt-offline set debian-update.sig --update`). Is this possible?

Comment: You could use something other than apt-offline. Just `dpkg --set-selections/--get-selections` would work, I think. But I don't fully understand your context, so it may not work for you.

Comment: @FaheemMitha specifically, I need to install `zookeeper-server` (from CDH) and all of its dependencies. Could you expand the `dpkg` suggestion in an answer? I'm not familiar.

Comment: What is CDH? The `--set-selections/--get-selections` is quite standard. Just do a search.

Comment: CDH is Cloudera's apt (and others) repo, where `zookeeper-server` is

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191662/4671